# How can I repair or replace this LED light fixture?

Tags: bathroom, shower, led, light

This is what it looks like. Do you know what it is?

[image: Light led for bathroom/shower]

Answer (score 3):

It's not meant to be repaired, and it looks like the circuit board with the LEDs on is broken beyond repair anyway.

Turn the power off.  Undo the two screws that hold it to the ceiling.  Disconnect it.  Throw it away.  Buy a new one and fit that.

Answer (score 2):

It is an LED light.

I imagine it does not turn on when you use the switch so imagine the LED driver stopped working (easiest), or that something is wrong with the circuit (wires in the walls--harder).

Replacement of the light after you turn off the breaker and check the power is off is probably in your future.

You might get lucky and can just replace the driver, instead of the whole light.

Comment: From the picture, it looks like someone has bashed the circuit board with the LEDs on.  I don't think replacing the driver will help.

Comment: @SimonB: that's probably just a thin plastic template that covers the expose surface-mount connections for safety: the LED chain probably runs at many dozens or even low-100s of volts, not something you want to brush up against while cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

LED lights don't have sockets because LEDs don't burn out.

What does, however, is the electronic module which converts AC power into the correct current of DC power to operate the LEDs.  That is called the "Driver".

Remove the fixture and you should be able to find the driver module pretty easily.  It will have labeling and may be socketed for easy replacement.

You can check with the fixture manufacturer or post a picture of the labeling and we should be able to identify the relevant specs.  Generally current must *a specific value* and voltage must be in a reasonable range for the LEDs in question.  You are probably accustomed to those being the other way 'round.

Comment: _re: "LEDs don't burn out"_ : LEDs _do_ most certainly burn out. In an assembly like a bulb, the driver circuitry is more often the culprit, but it's hyperbole to say the LEDs themselves don't. In fact, often as the driver goes it will briefly pass line voltage to the chain which destroys them instantly before the fusible resistor burns out. If you see a yellow chip with a black or brown dot in the middle, that's a burnt out LED.

Comment: @dandavis of course they *can be caused to* burn out by actively damaging them, as you say by driver-failure fratricide.  I'm saying the LEDs themselves are unlikely to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Disassemble**

You are going to have to take it off from the ceiling to access the back part.

Loosen the two screws then twist till it comes out.

On the back take a picture of the wiring then tug on the wires to make sure they were still connected, then disconnect the wires and take it off from the ceiling (with power off).

Probably need to replace the whole LED part.

Comment: @isherwood Disassemble it the tile, I clear explain the procedure after that